# Identificar los puntos en los que cambia el valor de una columna en un DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Dispongo de un DataFrame en el cual, en la columna 'Position' tenemos 0 y 1.

```
from datetime import datetime       
import pandas as pd
from math import floor
import yfinance as yf

Date = ['2018-02-06 ' , '2018-06-29 ', '2019-07-09 ', '2020-03-16 ', '2020-08-24',  '2020-12-03',  '2020-12-15','2021-01-08 ' , '2021-01-27 ','2021-04-16 ']
Close = [150.61, 160.08, 178.17, 140.35, 189.4, 200.6, 202.46, 209.26, 207.54, 230.39] 
Position = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]

data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Date, Close, Position)), columns =['Date', 'Close', 'Position']) 

data['Date'] = data['Date'].astype('datetime64') 
data
```

Necesito identificar los puntos en los que el valor en esta columna pasa, de 0 a 1 ó de 1 a 0.
Lo consigo de la siguiente manera.

```
for i in range (1, len(data)):
    if (data.loc[i, 'Position'] == 1) and (data.loc[i-1, 'Position'] == 1): # hold the position
        data.loc[i, 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Hold'

    if (data.loc[i, 'Position'] == 0) and (data.loc[i-1, 'Position']) == 0: # hold the position
        data.loc[i, 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Hold'
        
    if (data.loc[i, 'Position'] == 0) and (data.loc[i-1, 'Position'] == 1):    # sell
        data.loc[i, 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Sell'
                                          
    if (data.loc[i, 'Position'] == 1) and (data.loc[i-1, 'Position'] == 0):   # buy
        data.loc[i, 'Buy/Sell']  = 'Buy'

data[data['Buy/Sell'] != 'Hold']

    Date    Close   Position    Clave   Money   Buy/Sell
0   2018-02-06  150.61  1   NaN     0.0     NaN
1   2018-06-29  160.08  0   NaN     NaN     Sell
3   2020-03-16  140.35  1   NaN     NaN     Buy
6   2020-12-15  202.46  0   NaN     NaN     Sell
8   2021-01-27  207.54  1   NaN     NaN     Buy
```

Pero pienso que debería poder hacerlo de una forma más simple, con menos código, haciendo algún tipo de filtrado con esas condiciónes, directamente sobre la columna 'Position', sin tener que crear otra columna 'Buy/Sell. Agradeceré sugerencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu intuición es correcta, hay una forma mejor de hacerlo :-) En general, si te encuentras que estás implementando un bucle `for` para resolver algo con pandas, es un indicio de que debe haber una forma mejor.

En este caso creo que la clave es el método `.diff()` que puedes aplicar a una columna. Ese método resta a cada valor el anterior en la misma columna. Si sale 0 es que eran iguales. Veámoslo sobre tu dataframe de ejemplo:

```
>>> data
        Date   Close  Position
0 2018-02-06  150.61         1
1 2018-06-29  160.08         0
2 2019-07-09  178.17         0
3 2020-03-16  140.35         1
4 2020-08-24  189.40         1
5 2020-12-03  200.60         1
6 2020-12-15  202.46         0
7 2021-01-08  209.26         0
8 2021-01-27  207.54         1
9 2021-04-16  230.39         1

>>> data.Position.diff()
0    NaN
1   -1.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6   -1.0
7    0.0
8    1.0
9    0.0
```

Aquí puedes ver cómo (salvo el primer resultado que es NaN porque no hay dato "previo"), tienes 0 para los casos en que el valor no ha cambiado, 1 para los casos en que ha pasado de 0 a 1 y -1 para cuando ha pasado de 1 a 0. Solo con esto ya podrías rellenar de forma más simple tu columna "Buy/Sell":

```
>>> data.Position.diff().replace({-1.0: "Buy", 1.0: "Sell", 0.0: "Hold"})
0     NaN
1     Buy
2    Hold
3    Sell
4    Hold
5    Hold
6     Buy
7    Hold
8    Sell
9    Hold
```

Pero si, como dices, no necesitas realmente esa columna sino que sólo la usabas como paso intermedio, no necesitamos generarla. El resultado de `diff()` puede convertirse en un booleano, y el resultado será `False` en los lugares en que diff salió 0, o `True` en todos los demás, así que podrías usar esos booleanos para seleccionar las filas en que salga True, que es en aquellas en las que Position ha cambiado:

```
>>> data[data.Position.diff().astype(bool)]
        Date   Close  Position
0 2018-02-06  150.61         1
1 2018-06-29  160.08         0
3 2020-03-16  140.35         1
6 2020-12-15  202.46         0
8 2021-01-27  207.54         1
```

Como ves, el resultado saca exactamente las mismas filas que tu código, sin necesidad de bucles ni comparaciones, lo cual no sólo es más compacto y menos proclive a errores, sino además mucho más rápido por hacer uso de las operaciones internas de pandas, que son muy eficientes.